# Copying text from ReadOnly cell in Xceed PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I have ReadOnly properties binded to PropertyGrid and I want users to be able to select and copy text from cells. 
Do I need to use a different attribute? If so which  should I use? 
or maybe there is a different solution ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use [ReadOnly(true)] on the property.
But editing property's value at right-side in the xceed property grid can be restricted by making it as ReadOnly TextBox as follows:

.xaml:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="MyPrpGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
FontWeight="ExtraBold" ShowSearchBox="False" ShowSortOptions="False"
SelectedObject="{Binding BindedPropName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Background="#FF4A5D80" Foreground="White" >

<xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
    <!-- For Id, Text and Type fields at left-side in the xceed property grid, replace right-side value area with ReadOnly TextBox -->
    <xctk:EditorDefinition>
        <xctk:EditorDefinition.PropertiesDefinitions>
            <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="Id"/>     <!-- BindedPropName.Id -->
            <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="Text" />  <!-- BindedPropName.Text -->
            <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="Type" />  <!-- BindedPropName.Type -->
        </xctk:EditorDefinition.PropertiesDefinitions>
        <xctk:EditorDefinition.EditorTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Binded Value is a DependencyProperty which is defined in view model -->
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Value}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
        </xctk:EditorDefinition.EditorTemplate>
    </xctk:EditorDefinition>
</xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>

</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

MyViewModel.cs should be derived from DependencyObject.

MyViewModel.cs:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyViewModel),
                                                                                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
public string Value
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); } // GetValue() is from derived DependencyObject class
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }         // SetValue() is from derived DependencyObject class
}
```